# How to create outlook add in that open the task pane and read the attachments in the outlook mail?

Tags: outlook, azure-blob-storage, outlook-addin, office-addins, email-attachments

I want to create a outlook add-in for reading the attachments to the add-in and list the attachments to it. Then I want to store those attachments on the Azure Blob Storage. If it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.

First of all, you need to decide what kind of add-ins you need to develop for Outlook - COM or Web based add-ins. If you need to support only Outlook for desktop on Windows then your choice is VSTO, see [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) for more information. For Outlook web add-ins [Build your first Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator).

Both kind of add-ins allows running a task pane in Outlook with all the required information of attached files (or items).